# How to read a file from HDFS in map() quickly with Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to read a different file in every map() ,the file is in HDFS

```
  val rdd=sc.parallelize(1 to 10000)
  val rdd2=rdd.map{x=>
    val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://ITS-Hadoop10:9000/"), new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
    val path=new Path("/user/zhc/"+x+"/")
    val t=hdfs.listStatus(path)
    val in =hdfs.open(t(0).getPath)
    val reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in))
    var l=reader.readLine()
  }
 rdd2.count
```

My problem is this code

```
val hdfs = org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI("hdfs://ITS-Hadoop10:9000/"), new org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration())
```

takes too much running time, every time of map() needs to create a new FileSystem value. Can i put this code outside map() function so it doesn't have to create hdfs every time? Or how can i read files quickly in map()?

My code runs on multiple machines. Thank you!

Comment: Try moving `val hdfs` out of the map closure.

Comment: if the cardinality of the files is relatively small (10K is small) I wouldn't read it using BufferedReader but rather constructing files arborescence and read and unify RDDs along with what @tuxdna suggested.

Comment: @tuxdna I've tried to put it outside the map closure, but it has error "Task not serializable,Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem"

Comment: @eliasah The files are small, but I don't completely understand what you said ,are you suggesting load all the files i need into a RDD like Knows Not Much suggested?

Comment: I don't understand what KnowsNotMuch suggest to be honest.

Comment: @eliasah thanks!  But what is "constructing files arborescence and read and unify RDDs"? Can you explain a little more specific?

Comment: @haochizhang ,  just to understand well, you need to count the lines in each file from the files located under the same directory?

Comment: @user1314742 no, i don't need to count the lines, I need to read the file in the map closure, I write the code like that just to simplify the question. And   the files are in the same directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, I recommend the use of `wholeTextFiles` method wich will return pairRdd with the key is the file full path, and the value is the content of the file in string.

```
val filesPariRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://ITS-Hadoop10:9000/")
val filesLineCount = filesPariRDD.map( x => (x._1, x._2.length ) ) //this will return a map of fileName , number of lines of each file. You could apply any other function on the file contents
filesLineCount.collect()
```

**Edit**

If your files are in directories which are under the same directory ( as mentioned in comments)you could use some kind of regular expression

```
val filesPariRDD = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://ITS-Hadoop10:9000/*/")
```

Hope this is clear and helpful

Comment: Thank you for your help! That's what I need!  But what if the files are in different directories, and those directories are in the same directory, is there a similar method to do that?

Comment: @haochizhang have you tired with the solution for multiple directories?