# Read file path available in a dataframe and read content of those files using spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

I have a data frame as follows. It contains hdfs file path. I would like to read the values and then read the contents of the file. What is the best way to solve this without any nested RDDs leveraging parallel processing. I am using Scala 2.11 and Spark 2.1

```
+--------------------+
|               value|
+--------------------+
|hdfs://61.81.70.1...|
|hdfs://61.81.70.1...|
|hdfs://61.81.70.1...|
|hdfs://61.81.70.1...|
+--------------------+
```

**Edit based on Ankush answer:**
The files are huge and can't be read using wholeTextFiles

Thank you

Comment: Collect it into an Array of Strings and then map it with `sc.textFile`. You should have an array of RDDs

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
sc.wholeTextFiles("path/to/all/file")
```

[doc link for reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.3/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext)

It generates a Pair RDD with `key` => `filepath` and `value` => `content of file`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the response. I have to read the file contents line by line. From the docs I see wholeTextFiles method read the entire content as single record. Doc also says it gives bad performance for big files

Comment: you could use map  of your dataframe  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37108980/how-to-read-a-file-from-hdfs-in-map-quickly-with-spark )

Comment: I 100% agree with you. But from the docs **Small files are preferred, large file is also allowable, but may cause bad performance.**